# What is the maximum amount of medicine that could accumulate in the body if the compound has a half-life of 24 hours?

Tags: kinetics, medicinal-chemistry, pharmacology

> If a patient is prescribed 25 mg per day of a compound that has a half-life of roughly 24 hours, what is the maximum accumulated amount of the medicine that would build in the patients body?

Comment: 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st day: 25 mg

2nd day: (12.5 + 25) mg

3rd day: (6.25 + 12.5 + 25) mg

4th day: (3.125 + 6.25 + 12.5 + 25) mg

The amount get closer and closer to 50 mg but never exceeds it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a mathematical formula that would represent this idea? Something like $$ \sum_{k=25mg}^mx_.5k$$

Comment: @doremi the formula you would want in general would be $$25\sum_{i=1}^{k} (\frac{1}{2})^{i-1}$$ where $k$ would be the number of days you take the drug. As the answers have stated, as $k\to \infty$, the sum approaches 2 and after multiplying by daily dose you get 50mg.